# Open Jupyter notebook in committed image in docker container

Tags: bash, docker, jupyter-notebook, docker-container, docker-image

I used docker commit to commit my work on a Jupiter notebook on docker, but my computer crashed. When I try to run the docker container, I can't open the notebook at the time of latest commit.

The following bash commands yield:

```
docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS               NAMES
7f1b4d6a811f        iess:latest         "/bin/su -l pycbc -c…"   5 minutes ago       Exited (1) 5 minutes ago                        iess
0dcd955ad0b6        4028090df24a        "/bin/su -l pycbc -c…"   14 minutes ago      Exited (1) 11 minutes ago                       vibrant_minsky
d7d76573d511        4028090df24a        "/bin/su -l pycbc -c…"   2 days ago          Up 32 minutes               8888/tcp            relaxed_cartwright


docker images
REPOSITORY                              TAG                       IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
iess                                   latest                    6e07932643eb        9 hours ago         4.6GB
<none>                                  <none>                    dd24d1257a5c        10 hours ago        4.6GB
<none>                                  <none>                    0bdaeb277ab9        10 hours ago        4.6GB
<none>                                  <none>                    911e848f8167        12 hours ago        4.6GB
<none>                                  <none>                    de16c7fce855        20 hours ago        4.6GB
<none>                                  <none>                    147ed70ecf70        21 hours ago        4.6GB
<none>                                  <none>                    792f3f87b8ee        21 hours ago        4.6GB
<none>                                  <none>                    79cbcc4abc27        21 hours ago        4.6GB
<none>                                  <none>                    9abe343a42b1        21 hours ago        4.6GB
<none>                                  <none>                    aea2324b9902        44 hours ago        4.6GB
<none>                                  <none>                    760e78217518        2 days ago          4.6GB
```

I am not a docker expert (very very very newbie), but I wanted to open start the last container on the list (d7d76573d511), with the image on top of the list (iess:latest created 9 hours ago).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the new image: `iess latest 6e07932643eb` you need to stop the container `d7d76573d51` they are both trying to use the same port which is causing the new one to crash. To stop the container use `docker stop <CONTAINER ID>`